# VBScript - Change Group Type

Tags: vbscript, scripting, active-directory

I am using the below VBscript to change group type of couple of groups to Security. I am getting an error "The server is unwilling to process the request" when executing objGroup.setinfo.

Appreciate if someone can help to resolve this.

```
Dim strOU, strGroup, objOU, objGroup
Dim strFile, objFile, objFSO
Const ADS_GROUP_TYPE_SECURITY_ENABLED = &H80000000
Const ForReading = 1
Const ADS_NAME_INITTYPE_GC = 3
Const ADS_NAME_TYPE_NT4 = 3
Const ADS_NAME_TYPE_1779 = 1
Const ADS_GROUP_TYPE_UNIVERSAL = &H8


strFile = "c:\Temp\GroupNames.txt"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFile, ForReading)

Set objRootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
strDNSDomain = objRootDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext")

Set objTrans = CreateObject("NameTranslate")
objTrans.Init ADS_NAME_INITTYPE_GC, ""
objTrans.Set ADS_NAME_TYPE_1779, strDNSDomain
strNetBIOSDomain = objTrans.Get(ADS_NAME_TYPE_NT4)
strNetBIOSDomain = Left(strNetBIOSDomain, _
Len(strNetBIOSDomain) - 1)

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
strNTName = Trim(objFile.ReadLine)
If (strNTName <> "") Then
On Error Resume Next
objTrans.Set ADS_NAME_TYPE_NT4, strNetBIOSDomain & "\" & strNTName

End If

' Use Get method to retrieve Distinguished Name.
strUserDN = objTrans.Get(ADS_NAME_TYPE_1779)
wscript.echo strUSerDN
' Bind to user object in AD.
Set objGroup = GetObject("LDAP://servername
```

" & strUserDN)

```
objGroup.Put "groupType", ADS_GROUP_TYPE_SECURITY_ENABLED
objGroup.SetInfo

Loop
objFile.Close
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the group scope as well.  Instead of just "ADS_GROUP_TYPE_SECURITY_ENABLED", you need "ADS_GROUP_TYPE_[type]_GROUP Or ADS_GROUP_TYPE_SECURITY_ENABLED", where [type] is GLOBAL, LOCAL, or UNIVERSAL.

Comment: I made the changes, bit still recievig the same error. i am a newbie to VBscripting, if you can proivde me the code to change group type of bulk groups to "security", i will be grateful

Comment: [Further reading](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/20db6486-9b92-4a42-8bea-1a0f8b803c72/vbscript-to-change-group-type?forum=ITCG) seems to say that you need the type and scope together.  So instead of "ADS_GROUP_TYPE_SECURITY_ENABLED" you'd need "ADS_GROUP_TYPE_GLOBAL_GROUP Or ADS_GROUP_TYPE_SECURITY_ENABLED". Note that the "Or" is actually part of what needs to be there, it's not saying only type in one or the other. Note in the link the logic to check whether the group type is UNIVERSAL; otherwise, it is LOCAL and can't be changed to GLOBAL, or is already GLOBAL.

Comment: Thanks, specifying both the type and scope made it work like charm....i am very happy...thanks a lot !!!!

Comment: Yeah, I just figured that out and was about to put it in here. :-P I usually use PowerShell for this, so am not as familiar with doing it in VBscript. Also note that if you don't add the SECURITY_ENABLED part and just specify GLOBAL or UNIVERSAL, that'll make it a DISTRIBUTION group instead of a SECURITY group. I'll edit my answer accordingly.